# Declaring gradle dependencies with arguments

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-moduled Gradle project setup. I would like for a module to be able to accept an argument from a module that specifies it as a dependency. Can this be achieved?

Something like this in the parent module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':innerModule') {
        arg "foo"
    }
}
```

And the inner module would also have to declare the variable that gets assigned. `def arg = ""`? Really not sure on the correct syntax here.

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is create a build type variable, which I can then use for conditional logic in my project code. It is an Android project, but the one module it requires is non-Android. So I cannot use the `buildTypes` closure in that module, but I was hoping to feed a variable into the non-Android module once the parent Android module determines the build type. I feel like that should be possible

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your *specific* question is no.

However, if you describe *what* you are trying to achieve, maybe Gradle will be able to help you.

- What is this variable controlling?
- What is the effect of the different values?